# Is it possible to let date return its result in ISO 8601 format by default

Tags: default, date, environment

I want to change the behavior of the command date (possibly by setting some proper environment variable) such that it returns its output as if it was invoked as

```
date --iso-8601=seconds
```

1. **Is that possible and how does one accomplish this?**
2. **If one applies the searched-for trick, would it resrict the usage of the command date or would it still be possible to override my desired default behavior?**

Comment: Would an `alias` suffice?

Comment: It would be nice if you told us your Ubuntu version, etc when you ask Questions. See https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: The version of it is Xubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. But I suppose my question has the same answer in all versions of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` "`alias`es" are the answer. Here's a snippet from my `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
#
# Various timestamping commands
# ds 15Aug27
alias ds="date +%y%b%d"
# timestamp "11May14-191416"
alias timestamp="date +%y%b%d-%H%M%S"
# today "20110514"
alias today="date +%Y%m%d"
# tshhmmss "11May14-191540"
alias tshhmmss="date +%y%b%d-%H%M%S"
# tshhmm "11May14-1916"
alias tshhmm="date +%y%b%d-%H%M"
# tsymd "2011-May-14"
alias tsymd="date +%Y-%b-%d"
# tsjou "18-11-01 01:55:28" for journalctl --since
alias tsjou="date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"
# tsiso "2020-02-18T13:31:37-05:00"
alias tsiso="date --iso-8601=seconds"
```

The one you want is the last, `tsiso`.

Aliases make `date`, among other commands, much more useful. Read `man date;info date` and you can do almost anything with `date`.

Comment: Yes, your proposal solves my problem. I'd just use tsiso instead of the lengthy command and the name of the new command is easy to remember.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way solving this problem and the similar one for ls:

Add the following lines to the end of  `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
# 2020-02-23 hinzugefügt für Datumsformat ISO-8601 bei ls:
export TIME_STYLE=long-iso
alias ls='ls –color=auto'
# 2020-02-23 hinzugefügt für date (denn das reagiert nicht auf TIME_STYLE):
alias date='date -Iseconds'
```

In order to work for `ls`, you have to log out and log on again.

However, if you do it like this particular formatting e.g. to the second, you can't use any other formatting option for `date` any more to override it. It would be rejected as giving more than one formatting option. You can **overcome this by prepending a backslash in order to `unalias` the command `date`, e.g.: `\date -Ihours`.**

Still then you have to `unalias` the command `date` in any script you use. **Problems may arise if you use scripts written by someone esle unaware of `date` being modified!**

It would be nice if `date` would either also honour `TIME_STYLE` or just take the last option for each category if more than one is given. Then this would work seamless... Alas, things are different now!